# Can we steal more CPU time/Resource by having more(than other running apps on user machine) thread/process in an app?

Tags: multithreading, process, operating-system, cpu, scheduling

We know, the CPU Schedules thread. So if my app has much more thread than other apps, then will my app get more CPU time? I think OS can somehow prevent this since it knows which process these threads belong to. It can just assign lower priority to a process's thread if the process has numerous threads.

But What about Process? If an app has multiple processes, will it get more CPU time?

I also want to ask the same question about Resources. Since resources are allocated to the process, then if my app has multiple processes, then I can get more resources right?
For example, on an OS, a single process can take up to 2GB of memory, then if my app has two processes and there is enough memory, then it can take up to 4GB of memory. Right?

Answer (score 1):

This is very dependent of the target OS. On Linux, the scheduler is [CFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completely_Fair_Scheduler) which is fair (hence the name). So a user having more processes or threads will not steal (a lot) resources of another user. Linux schedule *tasks* that are threads in practice. It does not care whether an application have 1 process with many threads or many processes with one thread. The Windows scheduler is pretty different (same for MacOS). On Windows, the scheduler is not meant to be fair and what the process does also matters a lot. For example, a process doing IOs typically have a higher priority (i.e. *priority boost*). Ready threads also have a priority boost.

For the RAM, the amount of RAM a process can allocate is not really limited on 64-bit Linux and Windows by default (besides absurdly high values). In fact, the allocated memory is virtual memory and not physical memory. Memory pages are not mapped as long as they are not read/written. Having more processes does not have any impact on the amount of memory that can be allocated/used on 64-bit systems apart from using more memory due to the overhead of the process themselves. The limit of the memory *used* is set by the hardware (the RAM, the processor and the swap memory of the storage device). On 32-bit systems, each process have a limited virtual memory (typically 4 GiB) mainly due to pointers being 32-bit.

Comment: https://lwn.net/Articles/254711/ has info about the fact that Linux CFS implicitly groups by user and aims for fairness between those groups.  At least by default, if that config option is set.